# Sentence complements in questions

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence I am wondering if the word **what** functions as a sentence complement.

**What time is it?**

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you'd say it was an interrogative adjective in this context.

Comment: Thank you  very much for your answer which I agree with, but I want to know whether the word when can also be considered to be functioning as a complement.

Comment: Well, I guess you could see it that way. You could rephrase it as "the time is what," which would make it a kind of subject complement. Maybe I don't quite understand why it matters, but I guess the fact that "what" and "it" are referring to the same grammatical abstract could be important?